# Field 'maca' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Boss(models.Model):
   class Maca(models.IntegerChoices):
      one_maca = 1,
      one_macas = 2,
      two_maca = 3,
      four_maca = 4,
      six_maca = 5,
      __empty__ = _('Select')

  maca = models.IntegerField(
    db_column='Maca', choices=Maca.choices, blank=True, null=True
  )
```

forms.py

```
maca = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=Boss.Maca.choices, widget=forms.Select)
```

When I try to submit as empty value I got the following error

```
ValueError: Field 'maca' expected a number but got ''.
```

Comment: What do you expect after submitting the empty value?

Comment: When the empty value is selected, I want to send NULL in DB

Comment: Could you post the logic you use for 'submitting an empty value'? Are you using a form?

Comment: Yep, I'm using a form to submit value